# list only items you have access to

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

### background

I have a set of items that any user may append to, but you may only read/write items you own.

This is a simplified version of what I'm really working on. I can't just make `$uid` part of the path because these items are also shared to specific other users.

```
"session": {
  "$other": {
    ".validate": "(!data.child('owner').exists() && newData.child('owner').val() == auth.uid) || newData.child('owner').val() == data.child('owner').val()",
    ".read": "data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid",
    ".write": "newData.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Given the above rules a user may `push({ owner: my_uid })` into the list. I have verified that this user may read and write the newly created record.

### question

How can my user find all of the records it has access to?

Comment: You need to denormalize your collections so that `users` and `items` are separate from each other. Then you would add `$iid` to a given `$uid` or `$uid` to a given `$iid`.

Comment: I don't understand your response. Is my answer below what you're trying to explain? If not, how about posting an answer with more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
"session": {
  "index": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
      "$sessionid": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  },
  "$other": {
    ".validate": "(!data.child('owner').exists() && newData.child('owner').val() == auth.uid) || newData.child('owner').val() == data.child('owner').val()",
    ".read": "data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid",
    ".write": "newData.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

With this approach every time I create a `session/<id>/` I also create an entry under `session/index/<uid>/<id>`. Because any user can write to that address, but only you can read from it I should be able to share to another user by writing to their index.